# Why does this JS fail when I use a master page? (ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, autocompleteextender

I'm currently working on a project where I need to use a lot of AJAX AutoCompleteExtenders, and they have been working fine- but now I'm tidying up the code and implementing a master page, I'm running into issues. I have this JS:

```
$find('txtName')._onMethodComplete = function(result, context) {

$find('txtName')._update(context, result, false);
webservice_callback(result,context);
};
```

And when I load the page, this error occurs relating to that snippet:

Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'null' is null or not an object

Just to reiterate, this only happens when I have a master page for some bizarre reason. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried debugging on firefox using firebug? That has a good javascipt debugger, the internet explorer one is practically useless in comparison

Comment: @Hawxby - I disagree. The IE javascript debugger is far more useful than FireBug if you know what you are doing.

Comment: More so in 8 and further more in 9 but before that pretty awful. As I don't know the IE version in use on the work environment saying install firefox and firebug is likely simpler than update IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `<%=txtName.ClientID%>` because with master pages in use your ids will be mangled to avoid namecollision between masterpage and aspx/usercontrols etc.

However please note that to be able to use `<%=` you will have to include the JS in the ASP.NET markup code. This can be done with the IIS `#include` rather than using `script`'s src.

Example:

```
<!-- #Include virtual=".\JS\YourJSFileWithASPNETMarkup.js" -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Try View Source on your page and make sure that the <input> is still named txtName.  Sometimes with master pages, the name changes.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

('<%=txtName.ClientID>')._onMethodComplete = function(result, context) {

Answer (score 0):

If you're using .NET 4 then you could add `ClientIDMode="Static"` into the page directive, which would tell ASP.NET to keep it's mucky hands off the element IDs.

Answer (score 0):

When you use masterpage, the ID of your controls change, so you can't use the same ID in Javascript, instead you can modify your selector like this : $('input[id*="txtName"]') now it finds all the controls which have an id that contains txtName. there are different selectors of this kind that you can use.
[here is a useful link](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)